# How to write a sentence where last of three actives isn't something you play

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order

Does this sentence makes sense:

**In his free time, he likes playing cricket, table tennis, and gardening.**

(a person doesn't play gardening)

Is there an alternative way of writing this sentence without using the word "enjoy"? I used enjoy in the previous sentence.

Comment: Have you considered _he likes gardening and playing cricket and table tennis_?

Comment: he likes playing cricket and table tennis, and gardening.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other rewrites that sound better for various ways, but the official way to fix problems with non-parallel items in a series is to use "and" appropriately or to put the helping words in the right place.

> ... he likes playing cricket, football, and table tennis and gardening.

Honestly this is a bit confusing to read, but it's correct. Here, "playing" applies to the sports, and "gardening" gets its own "and" so it isn't part of the same series. You can improve the sound by re-ordering the items:

> ... he likes gardening and playing cricket, football, and table tennis.

Answer (score 1):

The word playing isn't required at all.

> He likes football, table tennis and gardening.

Now you might note that this doesn't distinguish between *playing* football and *watching* football.  That might not be a problem (most people who enjoy playing also enjoy watching)

You don't need to have just one sentence:

> He is a member of a football club and he plays table tennis. He is also a keen gardener.

Don't get trapped into using just one structure.  If something isn't working, break it up.  Here I haven't said "enjoy" or "like" at all! It is implied.